# How to call a function with variable number of parameters from a similar function?

Tags: c++, c, windows, mfc

Let me explain what I mean with the C++/MFC code below:

```
static CString MyFormat(LPCTSTR pszFormat, ...)
{
    CString s;
    va_list argList;
    va_start( argList, pszFormat );
    s.FormatV(pszFormat, argList);
    va_end( argList );

    return s;
}

static CString MyFormat2(int arg1, LPCTSTR pszFormat, ...)
{
    if(arg1 == 1)
    {
        //How to call MyFormat() from here?
        return MyFormat(pszFormat, ...);    //???
    }

    //Do other processing ...
}
```

How do I call `MyFormat()` from within `MyFormat2()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do that directly: once you open `va_list`, you cannot pass it on to a function that takes `...`, only to a function that takes `va_list`.

This does not prevent you from sharing variable-argument code among multiple functions that take variable argument lists: you can follow the pattern of `printf` + [`vprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vprintf/), providing an overload that takes `va_list`, and calling it from both places:

```
public:
static CString MyFormat(LPCTSTR pszFormat, ...) {
    // Open va_list, and call MyFormatImpl
}

static CString MyFormat2(int arg1, LPCTSTR pszFormat, ...) {
    // Open va_list, and call MyFormatImpl
}

private:
static CString MyFormatImpl(LPCTSTR pszFormat, va_list args) {
    // Implementation of the common functionality
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to move the parameter binding into `MyFormat2`. Like this:

```
if(arg1 == 1)
{
    va_list argList;
    va_start( argList, pszFormat );
    CString result = MyFormat(pszFormat, argList);
    va_end( argList );
    return result;
}
```

and handle parameters one by one inside `MyFormat`, or - like now - pass them to another function. You will also have to change the declaration of `MyFormat` to:

```
static CString MyFormat(LPCTSTR pszFormat, va_list argList)
```

Comment: Well, thanks. But I was looking to solve it with a function call and not the copy-and-paste-ed code.

Comment: You wanted to call `MyFormat` with passing the parameters. That's what this code does. Or at least it should.

Comment: Yes, that's what @dasblinkenlight suggested.

Comment: What does @dashblinkenlight s answer differ from my, other than explanation? He introduced a third function, I showed you how to keep two functions and solve the problem. Pick whatever you want, but please don't call an answer "copy-and-paste-ed code" when it actually __answers__ the question.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation. And I did not call your answer "copy-and-paste". I called that your original suggestion that you have edited since then. In that post you suggested putting my `MyFormat` function contents into the `if(arg1 == 1)` scope. dasblinkenlight on the other hand answered correctly before you (which you now suggest as well) and thus my upvote for his answer...

Comment: My answer got edited once, and I only added the second strip of code (the declaration of `MyFormat`), since I forgot about it. The rest remained the same from the moment I've posted :)